# Xcode Adding Subview on entire screen above everything

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to use addSubview method to add new view on my screen. However, new view must also include navigation bar etc. which means it should include entire screen. What should i do?

Whenever i try to addSubview it always shows new view under navigation bar.

I don't want to use pushViewController or presentModelViewController because new added view will be low opacity and i can see background but i do not want to interact with background objects like bar buttons table etc.
Sorry for english, i hope, i clearly told what problem is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just set the `frame` property of the view you add before, and set it with screen bounds.

```
[myView setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:myView];
```

If you want to disable interaction with the navigation bar :

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: didn't work, still not covering navigation bar. entire screen except navigation and status bars

Comment: who is the reciever of `addSubview:` in your implementation ?

Comment: Ah my mistake i was trying to add subview on self.view. it Solved my problem. However, still eventhough new view covers navigation bar, it interacts with navigation bar button. Is there any chance to cut interaction or should i disable programmatically all buttons,tables  etc. whenever i added subview

Comment: Thank you very much. I must disable all interactions programmatically after added subview. thanks again : )

Comment: This solution worked for me. But I had to add this line -> myView.layer.zPosition = 1000

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at adding another UIWindow above your root window.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried doing the navigationController.view addSubview, it wouldn't cover my tab bar so I did the following with my app delegate's window:

```
[self.window addSubview:myView];
```

if you need access to your appDelegate from another class, you'd just import your application delegate and call it from that.